# Update statement that includes a hyperlink in the column assignment in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is quite rudimentary but I've been wasting time on this. In the past I would normally do this update directly using the Design View however with this particular requirement I have to write a native query to perform this update. The update is shown below:

```
update TableA
set ColA='Some Value', ColB='Some value that redirects to this link <a href='http://www.google.com' />'
where ColC='Some condition'
```

It is important to ponder that ColB's data type is an nvarchar(max) and not a hyperlink. I am getting an Invalid syntax error on the first slash ('/') in the url. Does anybody know how to go about this?

Comment: You need to escape the inner quote marks with extra `'` characters

Comment: escape the `'` chars in your string by doubling them `''` (*or use double quotes `"` instead*)

Comment: @ADyson Please post your comment as an answer. That solved the problem.

Comment: No need since this is a common problem and there are many previous questions on the same topic